# how to join rows under the condition that the rows of the two columns have to equal each other

Tags: python, pandas

```
dict_1 = {'Col 1':[1,2,3,4],'Col 2':[3,11,32,33],'Check':[0,0,0,0]}
dict_2 = {'Col 3':[1,3,4,5,6],'Col 4':[23,3575,765,23,23]}
```

So what I want to do is see if Col 1 exits in Col 3 and if it does then I join the rows so the final df should look like:

```
df = {'Col 1':[1,2,3,4],'Col 2':[3,11,32,33],'Check':[1,0,1,1],'Col 3':[1,3,4],'Col 4':[23,3575,765]}
```

I tried to

Comment: Your expected results dataframe is invalid because it does not have the same number of elements in all dict value lists. It'll throw an error when you try to construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
col1set = set(dict_1['Col 1'])
join = ((c3, c4) for c3, c4 in zip(dict_2['Col 3'], dict_2['Col 4'])
        if c3 in col1set)
col3, col4 = zip(*join)
result = {**dict_1, 'Col 3': list(col3), 'Col 4': list(col4)}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but could you do this using pandas?

Comment: @Skandan Sorry but I don't like answering a question and then the goal post gets moved to something completely different afterwards.

Comment: Thats alright, it was my mistake not to add the pandas tag.